# Getting multiple number from a string

Tags: php, string, dynamic, numbers, extract

I have a form and one of the input names has numbers that correspond to information in my database. I need to extract the numbers and set them as variables so I can use them to store and retrieve data from the database.

Example: rdobtn_1_15 or qtybx_9_82

then numbers will be dynamic and will change so I need something that will get the numbers whether they are "20" or "5327"

Comment: [`explode('_', $yourString)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Huh? Give us sample input and correct, desired output.  But first, show us what *you've tried*.

Comment: What's the relation between 1,15,9,82 in your string and 20 or 5327?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$input = 'rdobtn_1_15'
$matches = null;
$returnValue = preg_match('/_(\\d+)_(\\d+)/', $input, $matches);
```

Your matches will be stored as

```
array (
  0 => '_1_15',
  1 => '1',
  2 => '15',
)
```

So your numbers are accessable via

```
echo $matches[1] // 1
echo $matches[2] // 15
```

For reference: [Regular Expressions](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_Expression)

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the digits from a string, if this is what you want to achieve, with:

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $your_string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: In this case the so called input names are not allowed to contain numbers itselves. Because we don't know exactly if this is possible you should choose '!_(\\d+)_(\\d+)!'.
In addition you forgot the first '\' before 'd' for escaping the second.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = explode('_', $string);

$element = $array[5]; // or whichever element you want
```